# Top offset of TableView embeded in Navigation Controller in storyboard

Tags: xcode, ios6, storyboard, tableview, navigationbar

I have custom TableViewController with plain style Table View and it is embeded in Navigation Controller. I use Refresh Control on the table view and Black Translucent style of the navigation bar and all is setup in storyboard.

The first row of the table view starts right under the navigation bar item, which is ok, and the rows can scroll under the navigation bar which is semi transparent. When user starts to pull the table down to activate Refresh Control, the animation of the refresh object obviously starts at the edge of the screen under the Navigation Bar, and so the refresh object is always partially covered by the navigation bar which can confuse inexperienced users.

Is there a way to tell the TableView to avoid scrolling under the navigation bar and start the refresh control object animation right under the navigation bar? I tried to play with Scroller Insets on table view without any effect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into the properties for the tableview controller in your storyboard, you can change the size and positioning of the tableview to start after the navigation bar.  The problem isn't an offset, but the size and position of the tableview itself.  Just move the y position down to accommodate the nav bar.